# What is our policy regarding Apple developer questions covered under NDA?

Tags: discussion, legal, terms-of-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do some of the questions/answers of Stackoverflow break SDK agreements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40889/do-some-of-the-questions-answers-of-stackoverflow-break-sdk-agreements)

Should they be allowed to close naturally, or killed with fire?

I've skimmed our [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal) but I didn't see anything that expressly forbids questions like these.

Comment: This could apply to anything covered by NDA. Most of the time I guess you just wouldn't know it.

Comment: Just as a reference, [this question sparked the interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939638/how-do-you-sort-the-file-list-in-xcode-4)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: "How do you sort the file list in Xcode 4?" (deleted) is supposed to be confidential information? Now that is just a *little bit* paranoid...

Comment: Its easy for me to say @Piskvor, but I would argue that what Xcode 4 does or looks like is confidential. How one small detail of it works... Isn't worth anyones time to fight over

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: You're right; it's Apple's code anyway, so they can be paranoid about it all they want.

Comment: `In Xcode 3 there was a menu option for sorting files in your project by name. This menu no longer exists in the same location (if at all) in Xcode 4.`  Take **THAT**, Apple!

Comment: I've commented on Apple-specific NDA issues [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-overf/49366#49366).  Generally, I just remind them in a comment of the NDA on prerelease material and point them to Apple's Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/ which have specific sections for answering questions on beta software.  Most of these questions end up being too localized, because they might only be issues affecting a specific beta build of the SDK, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see it as our problem, that a user breaks his NDA by asking a question here.

Especially if someone, who knows what the problem is about (possibly also under NDA) provides a solution without going into specifics, really what harm has been done? As long as the question doesn't reveal any confidential information, I don't really see a problem.

I believe this should only have to be deleted if one of the parties asks for it to be removed.

Disclaimer: I'm by no means a lawyer, this is just my opinion