# Limits of iOS 6 NDA

Tags: discussion, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do some of the questions/answers of Stackoverflow break SDK agreements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40889/do-some-of-the-questions-answers-of-stackoverflow-break-sdk-agreements)
>   [What is our policy regarding Apple developer questions covered under NDA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78609/what-is-our-policy-regarding-apple-developer-questions-covered-under-nda)

So I understand that, at the moment, asking specific questions about iOS 6 functionality is off-limits due to the Apple NDA. But we know that iOS 6 exists, and there is some general information available about new features. In answering or commenting on an non-iOS 6 question, is it permissible to *mention* iOS 6? And if it is, what might the limit of mentioning it be?

As an example: [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView) has been deprecated by its author due to a new feature in iOS 6 (the author explicitly mentions this in the read me). Can I comment on a post about KKGridView  to reiterate what the author says?

Comment: One workaround would be to describe iOS 6 as "the OS that must not be named." Seriously though, related (and suggesting that it's not SO's business to enforce NDAs in the first place): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78609/what-is-our-policy-regarding-apple-developer-questions-covered-under-nda

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-over/49366#49366

Comment: That makes complete sense, I hadn't thought of it from that perspective. Still, SO users do their own enforcing in a way, so I wonder where they would consider the line being.

Comment: Apple can take its NDAs and shove it up their cupertino.  We aren't Apple, we aren't responsible for enforcing their stupid developer NDAs.  Waste of everybody's time.

Comment: Did you sign anything keeping you from talking about iOS 6? If you did, you can rest assured that I did not. Please point me to the question and I'll add the necessary comments relating to iOS 6.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

iOS 6 itself is not under NDA. If it were, Apple would be implicating everyone by announcing it publicly at WWDC...

Most development content and APIs related to the iOS 6 SDK, however, are under NDA as long as the SDK hasn't been released to the public developer community. Only certain features which have been publicly announced or are available for public viewing on Apple's site are individually not bound by NDA. Theoretically these topics can be covered, but it's painfully easy to venture into forbidden territory, which is why it's generally advised that we keep all discussion of iOS 6 development to the [Apple Developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com). Besides, if anyone is in the best position to answer questions about iOS software that is in still in early-stage development and testing, it is Apple itself.

We don't forbid questions about iOS 6 or any other development that concerns NDA-bound content *per se*; in fact, we are not responsible for a developer violating their NDA at all, because the developer is the one who signs the agreement, not Stack Exchange. It is the developer's responsibility and discretion to know what to talk about... and what to keep under wraps.

That said, most questions on Stack Overflow relating to code not working in this beta or that beta can be safely closed as too localized, and that's how we already handle most questions about beta platform development. Just remember that "too localized" does not mean "is bound by NDA and shouldn't be discussed here".

Comment: I sign many NDAs (including this one), and one of the key lines from the confidentiality agreement I link to in [my earlier answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-over/49366#49366) is this: "Apple Confidential Information will not include: (i) information that is generally and legitimately available to the public through no fault or breach of yours". If Apple shows something publicly, or someone breaks NDA and posts it as part of their question or project, there's little danger in discussing that one item.

Comment: Also, the beta period for one of Apple's products is one of the few times that I direct people to Apple's developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/ over Stack Overflow, because not only can items under NDA be discussed there, but the Apple engineers working on the frameworks regularly participate in the discussions during this period. It's a great way to not only learn what's going on with the new OS, but also to help steer its evolution.

Comment: Just because its beta doesn't mean it will be removed/changed before release.  I'd support the assumption that beta questions will still have some relevance for future developers, the same way we don't reject questions about version 2 of Foo when in version 3 feature Bar has been depreciated.

Comment: @Won't: That too. We can always wait and see, and deal with them later.