# Apple OS X Developer Program: can I ask questions about the new API?

Tags: discussion, scope, api

Is it allowed to ask questions on a public forum (*^H^H^H* or Q&A) regarding features of an API that is only available to (paid) members of the Apple Developer Program (ADP)?

*I would say that those questions are very valuable, not only because current members gain a better understanding due to the discussion on Stack Overflow, but also because potential members may actually join the paid ADP and then start working with the new API.*

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to, the API will eventually be available to everyone won't it? When that happens we'll already have a bunch of questions answered.

Comment: My apologies ;-D   Should have said "public forum (or Q&A)"!

Comment: @Ben: sure but if apple feels very protective about cool new feature X, they might get ticked off if I discuss it openly!

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd [You might want to link this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/155556)  ^_^

Comment: @ama you just did! Actually, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/152859) is nothing short of exceptional, cheers! :)

Comment: See also [As an iPad/iPhone/iPod touch developer, what can't I ask or answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-over)

Comment: Apple's developer NDA is annoying as hell.

Comment: The apple developer forum "OS X Mountain Lion Developer Preview" (https://devforums.apple.com/community/mac/pre) has a big red bar **Apple confidential information** above it. That clearly indicates where Apple stands in this. I guess that does answer my question (I was new to both meta and the apple osx developer forum, apologies!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, the rule is simple. If the API is publicly available to free and non paid Apple developers, it can be asked about without any issue. This actually covers around 90% of the developer documentation Apple provides.

For the other 10%, If the API is explicitly listed by Apple as being under NDA and/or in Beta, as was the case with, for example, iOS 5, start treading lightly. No one can prevent you from asking those questions, however, do not be surprised if Apple disables your paid account for violating the NDA*.

Also, your target audience is really limited to other developers under the same NDA, and some might not even be bothered to answer your question in public, and often the best answers for these questions are actually found at the Apple Developer Support forum.

<sub>* I personally know of 3 actual instances where this has happened, none from SO that I am aware of however.</sub>

Comment: Our offical stance on NDA seems to be "it's your problem" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40891/166936 if something violates an Apple NDA, Apple can contact the SE team. Mods/ect can't police this crap

Comment: Yes, when it comes to content under still under NDA, the [Apple Developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/) are really the best place to go. When something's in the beta period, I've found that the Apple engineers tend to participate in the forums quite regularly, so you'll be able to get answers right from the horse's mouth while the rest of us are still puzzling out the new stuff. Also, things have a tendency to break build-to-build during the beta stages, which you can keep up on there, but we'd close as too localized here.

Comment: @Diago: I find the SO community to be extremely helpful and responsive, so it would have been a nice place to also ask questions about 10.8 developing. But it does seem that the Apple forum is the place to go as long as 10.8 is under an NDA, even for the questions....